# Move elements one below other in block

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this little problem with my site. I want to move block title and second line to center, and button to keep in at center too, something like this:

[image how wanted to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwRbS.png)

Currently it looks like this:

[current look on block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiqBd.png)

Where can be seen this form is [here](http://54.201.121.83/) at bottom of page. This is what I do to customize it myself, I updated this CSS class:

```
.heading {
font-family: GOTHAM-BOLD;
font-size: 28px;
color: #273a55;
margin-left:340px; // i added this line, but seems it mess entire look.
}
```

and this is PHP code from that form:

```
<div class="footer box">
<div class="bluebg box"></div>
<div class="container">

    <div class="footermain box">
        <div class="footertop box">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 nopd">
                    <div class="ftleft box">
                        <div class="ftlinner box">
                           <h1 class="heading"><?php echo (get_field('news_letter_title'))?get_field('news_letter_title'):get_field('news_letter_title', 'option') ?></h1>
                            <?php echo (get_field('news_letter_tag'))?get_field('news_letter_tag'):get_field('news_letter_tag','option') ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    <?php
    endwhile;
```

It seems that Heading title and line bellow that is contained into one class called `heading`. So question now is now to move to center to start looking like image provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps :

- Change your `col-md-6` class to `col-md-12` in both the text bloc and the button bloc.
- Add class `text-center` to the text column like this

  `<div class="col-md-12 nopd text-center" >`
- Add style `justify-content: center;` to `"footertop box"` like this :

  `<div class="footertop box" style="justify-content: center;">`
- Remove class `noleft` from button column and add `margin:0` to button

[image]

Comment: Your answer seems fine, but Start for free button seems to be moved a little to left. Can you check why is happening that?

Comment: I updated my answer with the final step. Just remove class `noleft`

Comment: Removed noleft from `<div class="col-5 noleft">` but i dont see change when reload the page..

Comment: Add style `margin:0` to button

Comment: Added margin:0 to button class, but not changed nothing.. see https://i.imgur.com/QjhqdTw.png?1

Comment: So you did not follow correctly the steps I provided. Show me the HTML to see if I could help further

Comment: Followed all your steps, and made changes.. But button is non alligned.

Comment: You should show me some HTML. Because I don't know what you have. As you can see it the picture I provided, it is centered.

Comment: Fixed by adding this into custom CSS !

`button.btns.wavity_trial_btn {
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 200px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand, you want to have the texts centered and the button below them
for quick solution, add this class to your css:

```
.footertop.box .row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

delete div's col-md-6 classes which are in div.row

Comment: Thanks for your asnwer. It seems that make change, but not how i need it. All content need to be centered into block, and button size not need to be affected. Currently size of button in form is too bigger then before. See how now looks. https://i.imgur.com/mJSpoXD.png?1    FOr that i posted How need to look in first post. :)